# How do i do concat more than one tag value in vtd XML?

Tags: xml, xpath, vtd-xml

How do I concatenate multiple tag values using XPATH on vtd XML?

```
  <pre>
      <a>
        <b>
           <c>Hi</c>  
           <d>Vtd</d>
           <e>Users</e>
        </b>
      </a>
  </pre>
```

I have tried to use the following unsuccessfully.

```
    Xpath: concat(\a\b\c, \a\b\d, \a\b\e)   Result is : Hi Vtd Users
```

If I use concat with this XPATH, I receive the following error:

```
    Error "Function Expr can't eval to node set"
```

Comment: which version of vtd-xml are u using?

Comment: Please paste sample code here

Comment: please use autoPilot's evalXPathToString() method

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are starting from the root node and that your [axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) are correct. The below XPath returns the desired output.

```
concat(pre/a/b/c, " ", pre/a/b/d, " ", pre/a/b/e)
```

Comment: @Bhuvanesh the above answer is sample xpath code. Is that what you mean by "Please send that Sample code"?